# Issues with the CSV upload

Tags: php, file-upload, csv, yii, yii-cmodel

I am trying to upload CSV file using an Yii framework. I have added the code below :

**Model**

```
<?php
    class Import extends CModel
    {
        public $name,$email,$doctor = 0,$hospital = 0,$diagnostic = 0;
        public function rules()
        {
            return array(
                array('name,email,doctor,hospital,diagnostic','required')
            );
        }

        public function  attributeNames()
        {
            return array(); 
        }
    }
?>
```

**View(index.php)**

```
<div class="form">
    <?php echo CHtml::beginForm('site/import',$method='post',$htmlOptions =array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
            <input type="file" name="filename" value="file">
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('name'=>'submitCSV')); ?>
            <?php 
                if(is_array($buffer))
                {
                    foreach($buffer as $line){ 
                        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
                        echo CHtml::activeTextField($buffer[0],'name',array('value',$line['name']));
                        echo CHtml::activeTextField($buffer[0],'email',array('value',$line['email']));
                        echo CHtml::activeTextField($buffer[0],'doctor',array('value',$line['doctor']));
                        echo CHtml::activeTextField($buffer[0],'hospital',array('value',$line['hospital']));
                        echo CHtml::activeTextField($buffer[0],'diagnostic',array('value',$line['diagnostic']));
            }}?>
        </div>
    <?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionImport()
{
    $model = new Import;
    $buffer = array($model);
    if(isset($_POST['submitCSV'])){
        $filename=$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
        $fp = fopen("$filename","r");
        if($fp){
            $i =0;
            while(($buffer[$i] = fgetcsv($fp,1000,",")) !== false)
            {
                $model = new Import;
                $model->name = $buffer[$i][0];
                $model->email = $buffer[$i][1];
                $model->doctor = $buffer[$i][2];
                $model->hospital = $buffer[$i][3];
                $model->diagnostic = $buffer[$i][4];
                $buffer[$i++] = $model;
            }
            if(!feof($fp))
                echo "Echo: Unexpected fgets() fail\n";
        }
        fclose($fp);
        unset($_POST['submitCSV']);
    }
    $this->render('index',array('buffer'=>$buffer));
}
```

**Issues facing with this code :**

1. Since `$line` is an instance of `Import`, i should be able to use the elements of object `$line` but I am not able to do that. I used `$line->'name'` for this, but i got this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''name'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
2. `$line` is a `model` here, so I should be able to place it as the first argument in the `activeTextField` statements. I get this error : get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given
3. Thirdly, this code generates same rows of text-field five times, so i thought of experimenting the `activeTextField` by placing `$i` in place of `0` in the code and incrementing it in the `foreach` loop. That creates the same error as in 2.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use [`CFormModel`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormModel) instead of `CModel`. You may want to remove the `attributeNames()` function too.

issue 1: `$label->'name'` is incorrect. use `$label->name`.

issue 2 & 3 should work if you make changes as above

Comment: Since `CFormModel` is a subclass of `CModel`„ shouldn't the above code work with `CModel`?

Comment: @dlnGd0nG Now i get this issue : `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Though i needed to make several other changes, but you helped me out with pointing out the error in `$link->'name'`. Now it doesn't show me an error, `$link` wasn't an object. I tried checking it with `is_object`. And I am using `CModel` instead of `CFormModel`.